# Is there a package that I can use in order to get rules for a target outcome in R

Tags: r, optimization, arules

For example In this given data set I would like to get the best values of each variable that will yield a pre-set value of "percentage" : for example I need that the value of *"percentage" will be >=0.7* so in this case the outcome should be something like:

```
birds >=5,1<wolfs<=3 , 2<=snakes <=4
```

Example data set:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "birds    wolfs     snakes  percentage
3         8          7         0.50
1         2          3         0.33
5         1          1         0.66
6         3          2         0.80
5         2          4         0.74",header = TRUE
```

I can't use decision trees as I have a large data frame and I can't see all tree correctly. I tried the `*arules*` package as but it requires that all variables will be factors and I have mixed dataset of factor,logical and continuous variables and I would like to keep the variables and the Independent variable continues .Also I need "percentage" variable to be the only one that I would like to optimize. 
The code that I wrote with `*arules*` package is this:

```
library(arules)
dat$birds<-as.factor(dat$birds)
dat$wolfs<-as.factor(dat$wolfs)
dat$snakes<-as.factor(dat$snakes)
dat$percentage<-as.factor(dat$percentage)
rules<-apriori(dat, parameter = list(minlen=2, supp=0.005, conf=0.8))
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "get the best values of each variable" - do you mean the maximum value of each variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the question but to get the maximum value of each variable with the restriction of `percentage >= 0.7` you could do this:

```
lapply(dat[dat$percentage >= 0.7, 1:3], max)

$birds
[1] 6

$wolfs
[1] 3

$snakes
[1] 4
```

Edit after comment:

So perhaps this is more what you are looking for:

```
> as.data.frame(lapply(dat[dat$percentage >= 0.7,1:3], function(y) c(min(y), max(y))))
  birds wolfs snakes
1     5     2      2
2     6     3      4
```

It will give the min and max values representing the ranges of variables if `percentage >=0.7`

If this is completely missing what you are trying to achieve, I may not be the right person to help you.

Edit #2:

```
> as.data.frame(lapply(dat[dat$percentage >= 0.7,1:3], function(y) c(min(y), max(y), length(y), length(y)/nrow(dat))))
  birds wolfs snakes
1   5.0   2.0    2.0
2   6.0   3.0    4.0
3   2.0   2.0    2.0
4   0.4   0.4    0.4
```

Row 1: min
Row 2: max
Row 3: number of observations meeting the condition
Row 4: percentage of observations meeting the condition (relative to total observations)

Comment: Hello beginneR, thanks for your code. the question was how can I pull out the the best values of each variable that will yield in conjunction a pre-set value or range of "percentage".For example : If I would like to get percentage >= 0.7 I would need : birds >=5,1<wolfs<=3 , 2<=snakes <=4

Comment: Thanks beginneR, It close to what I was looking for. Is there a way to add the number and (%) of observations against the population that met the dat$percentage >= 0.7. The big problem here is:what happens you have very few cases that are far from the majority of values of a variable - In this case the range will be very wide, so this could be a big problem.